# Overlapping Days Calculation Nightmare

Tags: excel, date-arithmetic, lambda-calculus, sumproduct, overlapping-matches

There are 3 tables, 1) Slots, 2) Overlapping Dates and their Owners, 3) Owners Factors

I need to calculate (preferrably using a spill formula, but not mandatory) for each Slot (table 1) the number of **business days** in Overlapping Dates for each overlapping Owner (table 2) multiplied by the correspondent Factor (table 3).

Lastly, I'll calculate the business days multiplied by the number of Owners for each slot and will reduce the above figure... but this is the "easy" part of this calculation.

Image and Data Tables available below.

https://imgur.com/a/bZjdox9

Slots (table 1)

| Slot Start Date | Slot End Date | Slot Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21.Jun.2023 | 04.Jul.2023 | Slot 1 |
| 05.Jul.2023 | 18.Jul.2023 | Slot 2 |
| 19.Jul.2023 | 01.Aug.2023 | Slot 3 |
| 02.Aug.2023 | 15.Aug.2023 | Slot 4 |
| 16.Aug.2023 | 29.Aug.2023 | Slot 5 |
| 30.Aug.2023 | 12.Sep.2023 | Slot 6 |
| 13.Sep.2023 | 26.Sep.2023 | Slot 7 |
| 27.Sep.2023 | 10.Oct.2023 | Slot 8 |
| 11.Oct.2023 | 24.Oct.2023 | Slot 9 |
| 25.Oct.2023 | 07.Nov.2023 | Slot 10 |
| 08.Nov.2023 | 21.Nov.2023 | Slot 11 |
| 22.Nov.2023 | 05.Dec.2023 | Slot 12 |
| 06.Dec.2023 | 19.Dec.2023 | Slot 13 |
| 20.Dec.2023 | 02.Jan.2024 | Slot 14 |

Overlapping Dates and Owners (table 2)

| Overlap Start Date | Overlap End Date | Overlap Owners |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11.Sep.2023 | 30.Sep.2023 | Overlap Owner G |
| 25.Sep.2023 | 08.Oct.2023 | Overlap Owner E |
| 25.Sep.2023 | 06.Oct.2023 | Overlap Owner D |
| 27.Sep.2023 | 02.Oct.2023 | Overlap Owner J |
| 11.Oct.2023 | 24.Oct.2023 | Overlap Owner A |
| 25.Oct.2023 | 27.Oct.2023 | Overlap Owner A |
| 26.Oct.2023 | 11.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner H |
| 30.Oct.2023 | 07.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner J |
| 31.Oct.2023 | 01.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner C |
| 31.Oct.2023 | 03.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner A |
| 01.Nov.2023 | 01.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner I |
| 01.Nov.2023 | 02.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner B |
| 02.Nov.2023 | 03.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner G |
| 08.Nov.2023 | 10.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner B |
| 13.Nov.2023 | 17.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner B |
| 13.Nov.2023 | 16.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner F |
| 13.Nov.2023 | 13.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner I |
| 15.Nov.2023 | 15.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner K |
| 20.Nov.2023 | 24.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner I |
| 20.Nov.2023 | 20.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner A |
| 21.Nov.2023 | 21.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner H |
| 23.Nov.2023 | 23.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner G |
| 24.Nov.2023 | 24.Nov.2023 | Overlap Owner F |
| 30.Nov.2023 | 08.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner I |
| 04.Dec.2023 | 08.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner C |
| 06.Dec.2023 | 08.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner B |
| 11.Dec.2023 | 15.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner J |
| 13.Dec.2023 | 29.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner F |
| 14.Dec.2023 | 22.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner B |
| 16.Dec.2023 | 02.Jan.2024 | Overlap Owner K |
| 19.Dec.2023 | 19.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner A |
| 19.Dec.2023 | 29.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner A |
| 20.Dec.2023 | 01.Jan.2024 | Overlap Owner A |
| 20.Dec.2023 | 26.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner I |
| 21.Dec.2023 | 29.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner C |
| 27.Dec.2023 | 29.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner E |
| 27.Dec.2023 | 29.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner D |
| 27.Dec.2023 | 29.Dec.2023 | Overlap Owner L |

Owners Factors (table 3)

| Owners | Factor |
| --- | --- |
| Overlap Owner A | 0.5 |
| Overlap Owner B | 0.75 |
| Overlap Owner C | 0.375 |
| Overlap Owner D | 0.25 |
| Overlap Owner E | 0.5 |
| Overlap Owner F | 0.125 |
| Overlap Owner G | 0.25 |
| Overlap Owner H | 0.5 |
| Overlap Owner I | 0.75 |
| Overlap Owner J | 0.125 |
| Overlap Owner K | 0.375 |
| Overlap Owner L | 0.75 |

I tried SUMPRODUCT but I could not get the formula to calculate correctly the overlapping days as the formula below doesn't seem to work, let alone fit NETWORKINGDAYS in the middle of that.
=SUMPRODUCT(  (MAX(   MIN( slot_end_date, overlapping_end_date ) - MAX( slot_start_date, overlapping_start_date+1 ),   0   ))

The idea of using MINIFS and MAXIFS came to my mind but apparently I'ld need to approach that via Lambda or even a number of Lambdas in a LET function. That was when I stopped worring that I would get stuck if excel limitations or with performance issues as the actual data is about 10 times bigger than the sample I share here.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the tables @TomSharpe, I am not too familiar with how to correctly post tables here.

Comment: No problem - it just needed a blank line before each table. Can you tell me if the three tables in your sheet are actual Excel tables or just ranges plz? It would make a difference to any possible solution. BTW you are right that because max and min don't play well with array formulas you would either need a lambda or use if statements instead of max and min.

Comment: Thanks so much @TomSharpe for the help with the tables, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Answerting the questions @Tom-Sharpe - Table 1 (Slots) is an Excel table. Table 2 (Overlapping Dates and Owners) is also an excel table. A possible analogy to reduce abstraction would be taking Slots as "Projects" and Overlapping as "Holidays" and who is taking the holidays (Owners). The Factor table (table 3) is a range... a complicated one which at the moment is an array in the formula I am am trying to come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So at the moment I have just put in what should be the total of business days for each slot so you can check them. As you say, multiplying by the factors should be fairly straightforward after that. The calculation is just a variation on the standard Min-Max formula.

```
=SUM(BYROW(Table2,LAMBDA(r,LET(end,MIN(INDEX(r,2),[@[Slot End Date]]),start,MAX(INDEX(r,1),[@[Slot Start Date]]),
IF(end>=start,NETWORKDAYS(start,end),0)))))
```

[image]

Comment: You are an absolute star @Tom-Sharpe. That worked quite but slightly slow.
I think the issue is that for each row in Slot I am hitting Overlap and Owners multiple times. I was wondering if the function being outside of the Slot tables would help.
Alternatively if there was a way to replace Owners in Overlap for their Factors before getting into the Lambda would reduce the processing quite a bit.

Comment: =SUM(
   BYROW( TTable2,
      LAMBDA(_Row,
         LET(
            _EndDate, MIN(  INDEX( _Row, 2 ), [@[Slot End Date]]   ),
            _StartDate, MAX(  INDEX( _Row, 1 ), [@[Slot Start Date]]   ),

_Factor, VLOOKUP(  INDEX( _Row, 3 ), $L$3:$M$14, 2, FALSE ),

            _Factor * IF(  _EndDate>=_StartDate,  NETWORKDAYS( _StartDate, _EndDate ), 0   )
         )
      )
   )
)

Comment: The trouble is with taking the factor out of the lambda is that it has to somehow be part of the row of Table2 which is being processed by the lambda. The easiest way to do this would just be to add an extra column to Table 2 which contained each of the factors. Alternatively you could create a temporary array something like HSTACK(Table2,VLOOKUP(Table2[Overlap Owners],K3:L14,2,TRUE)) and access the fourth column of this array to get the factors. I have used TRUE in the vlookup because I noticed the owners were in alphabetical order - that would also speed it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks @Tom-Sharpe, that worked quite well. I've been merging and plugging other parts of the formula and spent a lot of time checking issues with the calculations where I found the data-set (Overlapping) has some overlapping entries itself (thanks to the user) that should not be double counted. Here is the entries:

Comment: | Overlap Start Date | Overlap End Date | Overlap Owners  |
|--------------------|------------------|-----------------|
| 19/12/2023         | 29/12/2023       | Overlap Owner C |
| 20/12/2023         | 01/01/2024       | Overlap Owner C |

Comment: I changed the calculation to creating an array for then to calculate the overlap but that didn't help. Maybe I am over-engineering this or missing something _Temp, MAKEARRAY(  ROWS(_Table2), 4, LAMBDA(_Row,_Col,IF( _Col=1,   MAX(  INDEX( _Table2, _Row, _Col ), _StartDate   ), IF( _Col=2,   MIN(  INDEX( _Table2, _Row, _Col ), _EndDate ), INDEX( _Table2, _Row, _Col )   )   )
))

Comment: It's starting to get beyond the scope of the original question. Are these regarded as errors and are there many of them? Maybe as a first step you could at least identify them with something like =COUNTIFS([Overlap Owners],[@[Overlap Owners]],[Overlap Start Date],"<="&[@[Overlap End Date]],[Overlap End Date],">="&[@[Overlap End Date]]) in Table 2. Otherwise you are right that you'd have to use the alternative approach of expanding each range into an array to coalesce the self-overlapping date ranges - do-able I suppose but could be slow and tricky to get working. Maybe post a separate question